# What does the `U` in `argparse.FileType('rU')` mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

In the following code, what does the `U` mean in `argparse.FileType('rU')`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Description")
parser.add_argument('--input-file', required = True, type = argparse.FileType('rU'))
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I checked the documentation for [`argparse.FileType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects) as well as the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function of python, but none seem to mention the capital `U`. What does it mean? What is different to `argparse.FileType('r')`?

Comment: Where did you find this code? And are you sure it works? (Maybe it is just a typo, I don't know)

Comment: It _is_ mentioned in the `open` docs, albeit as: _"Changed in version 3.11: The `'U'` mode has been removed."_

Comment: Okay so it definitely *was* a thing (and still is for most users because 3.11 is recent). From what a quick Google search gave me, it is related to line-ending handling